# Creating recurring Google Calendar events from Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

I'm attempting to set up yearly recurring events from a Google spreadsheet, and although I've followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515765/create-google-calendar-recurring-events-from-spreadsheet), I still can't get the ID to write to each row and thus allow me to write and check entries.

The column layout is

```
RenDate | Domain | Client | Type | Registrar | ID
```

Code:

```
/**
 * Adds a custom menu to the active spreadsheet, containing a single menu item
 * for invoking the exportEvents() function.
 * The onOpen() function, when defined, is automatically invoked whenever the
 * spreadsheet is opened.
 * For more information on using the Spreadsheet API, see
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet
 */
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Export Events",
    functionName : "exportEvents"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Calendar Actions", entries);
};

/**
 * Export events from spreadsheet to calendar
 */
function exportEvents() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headerRows = 1;  // Number of rows of header info (to skip)
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var calId = "[id removed]@group.calendar.google.com";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  for (i in data) {
    if (i < headerRows) continue; // Skip header row(s)
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date(row[0]);  // First column - Renewal Date
    var domain = row[1];          // Second column - Domain
    var client = row[2];          // Third column - Client
    var type = row[3];            // Fourth column - Type
    var source = row[4];          // Fifth column - Registrar
    var id = row[5];              // Sixth column - ID
    if(row[1]=="") continue;      // Skip rows if no date exists
    var title = type + " renewal for " + domain;
    var desc = "Renew with " + source + " for " + client;

    // Check if event already exists, update it if it does
    try {
      var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
      event.setTitle('got you');  // this is to "force error" if the event does not exist
    }catch (e) {
      var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, date, {description:desc});
      row[5] = newEvent.getId();   // Update the data array with event ID
      Logger.log('event created'); // For debugging
      var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(row[5]);
    }
    event.setTitle(title);
    event.setDescription(desc);
    var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addYearlyRule();
    event.setRecurrence(recurrence, date);
    debugger;
    data[i] = row ;
  }
  // Record all event IDs to spreadsheet
  range.setValues(data);
}
```

Debugging seems to be fine, but no events are created. I was able to create events using the `CreateAllDayEventSeries` function, but that seems to be impossible to work out with the ID approach, so that's why I'm trying this method.

**Edit**: Made change to continue function as caught by Serge insas.

Now the script is not finding the method for `createEvent` on the `catch` command.

Comment: Why did you write if (row[1]) continue?  This breaks the loop and the code does just nothing but continuing ...

Comment: That was just a way to check to see if that cell was empty; it worked on an earlier iteration. I'd still like that check to work, albeit a better way if that's the issue with the rest of the code completing.

Comment: Then it should be if(row[1]=="")... to skip empty rows

Comment: still not working ? Could you try to add a `Logger.log(row[i]` inside the loop to see the exact row content ?

Comment: The catch `createEvent` method is failing, and the log just shows the first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue on my own (although thanks again to Serge for some excellent assistance initially and a solid answer, even though I didn't see it before I fixed the issue). Here's the code I eventually settled with:

```
/**
 * Adds a custom menu to the active spreadsheet, containing a single menu item
 * for invoking the exportEvents() function.
 * The onOpen() function, when defined, is automatically invoked whenever the
 * spreadsheet is opened.
 * For more information on using the Spreadsheet API, see
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet
 */
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Export Events",
    functionName : "exportEvents"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Calendar Actions", entries);
};

/**
 * Export events from spreadsheet to calendar
 */
function exportEvents() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headerRows = 1;  // Number of rows of header info (to skip)
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var calId = "[id withheld]@group.calendar.google.com";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  for (i in data) {
    if (i < headerRows) continue; // Skip header row(s)
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date(row[0]);  // First column - Renewal Date
    var domain = row[1];          // Second column - Domain
    var client = row[2];          // Third column - Client
    var type = row[3];            // Fourth column - Type
    var source = row[4];          // Fifth column - Registrar
    var id = row[5];              // Sixth column - ID
    if(row[0]=="") continue;      // Check to see if date exists
    var title = type + " renewal for " + domain;
    var desc = "Renew with " + source + " for " + client;

    // Check if event already exists, update it if it does
    try {
      var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
    }catch(e){
      //Do nothing
    }
    if(!event){
      var newEvent = cal.createAllDayEventSeries(title, date, CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addYearlyRule(), {description:desc});
      row[5] = newEvent.getId();   // Update the data array with event ID
      Logger.log('Event ID ' + row[5] + ' created'); // For debugging
    }
    else{
      var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(row[5]);
      event.setTitle(title);
      event.setDescription(desc);
      Logger.log('Event ID ' + row[5] + ' already exists'); //For debugging
    }
    debugger;
    data[i] = row ;
  }
  // Record all event IDs to spreadsheet
  range.setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that date check issue; I'll correct it.

And in fairness, I did not have the luxury of waiting around for another response. I recognize that you were working to help find a solution, so I don't fault you for that in the least (and I do respect that you found another solution), but it's also pretty disrespectful to suggest that I didn't "try hard before asking." Maybe next time, leave personal comments out of it.

Comment: You're right, I was probably a bit nervous or tired or both...,I'll remove this comment -  Please accept my apologies.

Comment: Thank you. For what it's worth, you do really solid work helping with these issues, from what I've seen on other answers, and I respect the hell out of you for that, even beyond your help with this question.

Comment: That's nice  ;-) I appreciate a lot and renew my apologizes.

Answer (score 1):

I found that you were making a few errors (minimal) that prevented it to work.

One detail : you tried to create events with a single date, this works only for allDay Events so I guess that's what you wanted to do.

below is the full working code :

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Export Events",
    functionName : "exportEvents"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Calendar Actions", entries);
};

/**
 * Export events from spreadsheet to calendar
 */
function exportEvents() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var headers = data.shift();
  Logger.log(data);
  var calId = "h22nevo15tm0nojb6ul4hu7ft8@group.calendar.google.com";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    Logger.log(row);
    var date = new Date(row[0]);  // First column - Renewal Date
    var domain = row[1];          // Second column - Domain
    var client = row[2];          // Third column - Client
    var type = row[3];            // Fourth column - Type
    var source = row[4];          // Fifth column - Registrar
    var id = row[5];              // Sixth column - ID
    if(row[0]=="") continue;      // Skip rows if no date exists
    var title = type + " renewal for " + domain;
    var desc = "Renew with " + source + " for " + client;

    // Check if event already exists, update it if it does
    try {
      var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
      event.setTitle('got you');  // this is to "force error" if the event does not exist
    }catch (e) {
      var newEvent = cal.createAllDayEvent(title, date, {description:desc});
      row[5] = newEvent.getId();   // Update the data array with event ID
      Logger.log('event created'); // For debugging
      var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(row[5]);
    }
    event.setTitle(title);
    event.setDescription(desc);
    var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addYearlyRule();
    event.setRecurrence(recurrence, date);
    debugger;
    data[i] = row ;
  }
  // Record all event IDs to spreadsheet
  sheet.getRange(2,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```